# Can I install Dishonored 2 exclusively from CD without additional downloads?

Tags: dishonored-2

I recently purchased a physical copy of Dishonored 2. Now I wanted to install the game from the CD as its roughly 37 GB and my internet download speed is horrible.

However, every time I try to install on from the CD, it usually gets stuck around 148 of 37892 MBs, then proceeds to download the rest of the 36 GB. Is there a way to completely install dishonored from my CD?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.

Dishonored 2 comes with a DVD, which just can't hold all the required installation files
(9.4 GB of disk space vs. ~40 GB of game files).
The DVD is supposed to help installing the game by supporting you with a basic installation kit, but it will still be necessary to download the rest of the game files.

Answer (score 11):

Others have already pointed out that the game is mostly downloaded and is far larger than the DVD can handle. I'm suggesting an alternative way that mostly avoids having to download over a slow connection.

While not completely installing from the DVD, what you can do is start the download so it has allocated space, but hasn't yet downloaded the game. Then go to a friend who owns the game and has it downloaded on PC, copy the contents of their installation folder to a large enough USB or other portable medium, then copy it over to your local machine in your steam library folder (usually `$STEAMROOT$\steamapps\common\$GAMENAME$`). if you then verify game files through the Steam client, it should detect an install, maybe install some minor files that aren't in the folder and verify that all other files are the right ones.

Comment: You don't need to start the download and let it allocate space- you're just going to confuse your HDD and OS with this. Granted, they'll figure it out and fix it, but it's a completely unnecessary step. Steam doesn't even download things straight to the `\steamapps\common\$GAME$` folder, it goes to a temp folder (to avoid overwriting game files with an update that ends up corrupt for some reason) and is then copied once finished.

Comment: Right, the authentication is tied to your account, so starting the install is not required to "get legal." Still, a good method if one has limited bandwidth and a friend with the game. (Edit: though not sure if "denuvo" requires a secondary install)

Comment: Steam has a built-in game backup option, it sounds less crude than copying files manually.

Comment: Note that while this may work it's a whole lot of work for something unlikely to have any long term benefit. As in, tomorrow Bethesda could decide to change something in the game and your client will download a huge patch which will mostly negate the work you've done to try and limit your download bandwidth.

Comment: @TomKidd They're not going to release a patch anywhere near 37 GB in size though. Having to download only a 100 MB patch instead of a 37 GB game is still a huge benefit.

Comment: @TomKidd Most games these days have the bulk of their size in assets: sound files, textures and models. These are only changed or added to when a patch introduces new content (which is usually DLC that is downloaded separately), or when a fix is needed to a file. now, Dishonored 2 does have some performance issues on PC, which often require somewhat larger patches to fix, but those patches are unlikely to be much larger than a few GB at most. And long term, you're going to have to download those patches anyway, whether you download the game or copy it over.

Comment: @ChrisHayes The 2016 PC game DOOM, also published by Bethesda, regularly has 12-20 GB patches and updates. It's currently taking up over 70GB on my hard drive, and the disc for the PC version was about 8 GB or so, so that's at least 62GB I've had to download over the course of the last few months. The game Witcher 2 had a patch that required the re-download of the whole 9GB game. I agree that patches are usually not huge but they can be and I think your effort would be better served finding a coffee shop with good Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't install Dishonored completely from your DVD, since the DVD isn't even large enough to hold the complete install as dly already pointed out.

But you can install Dishonored without downloading it yourself, even without a crude workaround like in Nzall's answer, if you know somebody personally that owns Dishonored 2 on Steam.

He can create a backup of his install in the Steam context menu of the game and give it to you on a usb stick or several DVDs. Then you can use these files to install it on your account with the "Backup and Restore Games..." option in the Steam menu.
You will still need an active internet connection for Steam to verify that you own that game, but the game files itself should be completely covered by the files in the backup.

Comment: 37GB also fits on a dual layer BD-R.

Comment: You don't need to know someone who owns the game if you know someone you trust enough to log into steam on his PC. Just log into steam at a friends PC, download the game, create a backup, delete it from his PC and take the backup with you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install it with a slow connection, but it will take you a lot of time. Basically, 36 GB divided by your connection speed. If you are downloading at 100 KB/S, that will be 36GB in 360,000 seconds, which is 100 hours.

There is however no way to install it without the internet connection.

Comment: While technically true, it doesn't really answer the question, which is if he can cut off the connexion altogether. I presume this is why you got downvoted.

Comment: Yeah, title originally was "can I install with a slow internet connexion".

Answer (score -1):

1st of all apologize if my english not perfect,,

I found a tips still make mi waste less time installing on Steam

So i have the dishonored 2 dvd version and you can run the 1st 5gb installing from disc, then it will finish install from the disc an from the steam network same time

1st thing, for that small procedure if yu have set up your log in password on automatic, tek it out

1- put yur dvd on the computer
2- Connect to your steam account => Library => right clic on your game (dishonored2) = select "delete the local files" (sorry my steam in other language not sure the translate,,but it s same thing when u delete a game) => then confirm and quit steam
2- do the combination "windows + r" to open execut command

type in:   "C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe" -install E:

(replace E by the one you have for your dvd player if it s not the same,,and same thing for C if your steam is somewhere else)

3- clic on OK and steam gonna start and ask for your identification if yu didnt ask to save your password,,installation should start now from the disc

so fot the timing,,it took about 15min installe to 5.5gb on 30,,then from this point it continue installing both from disc an from network
my speed was 5 to 10mb/s for the 1st 5 gb instal,,then for the last 25gb it took mi 4hours,,around 2mb/s steam download and same time disc using like 5mb/s

so this will make your save some of your time,,but not the miracle solution :p still,

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade! This looks like good advice. However, the question was simply asking if you could install Dishonored 2 without additionally downloads, but it looks like your answer is telling the OP *how* to download it faster. To that end, I don't think this really answers the question.